# Storyshots jest - Cannot find module '@storybook/react' from 'index.js'

Tags: jestjs, storybook

I am trying to incorporate storyshots in my project.
I have this jest config:

```
"moduleFileExtensions": [
  "json",
  "js",
  "jsx"
],
```

Here is my test file content:

```
import React from 'react';
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';
import initStoryshots from '@storybook/addon-storyshots';

import IconCell from './';
initStoryshots({
    framework: 'react'
});
test('iconcell', () => {
    expect(renderer.create(<IconCell size="normal" type="pause" />).toJSON()).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

But it throws error:

```
Cannot find module '@storybook/react' from 'index.js'
```

The error thrown in `node_modules/jest-resolve/build/index.js`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Make sure you install `@storybook/react` npm module
2. Check the version of the storybook. Version 2 had the `@kadira` namespace, but version 3 has a `@storybook` one. There might be a clash of incompatible base and addon.

Comment: Thank you. I solved it exactly as u said on my own, accept it as an answer.